# The Formula of $\arcsin z$ without $\pm$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's first prove $e^z$ is onto on $\mathbb{C^*}$. So $\forall \omega \neq 0, e^z =\omega $ has at least one solution.

\begin{align*}
e^{x+iy} & = \rho e^{i\theta} \\
e^{x}+e^{iy} & = \rho e^{i\theta} \\
\end{align*}

Hence, $\forall \rho > 0$ we have $x = \ln(\rho)$ and $\forall \theta $ we have $y = \theta + 2k\pi$.

---

\begin{align*}
 \sin z = \omega  & \Rightarrow \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i} = \omega \\
     & \Rightarrow e^{iz} \left( e^{iz} - e^{-iz} \right) = 2i \omega \\
     & \Rightarrow \left(e^{iz}\right)^2 - 2i \omega \left(e^{iz}\right) - 1 = 0 \\
\end{align*}

So we solve $X^2 - 2i \omega X - 1 = 0$ hoping that whatever $\omega$ is, we wont end up with double roots $X=0$ (since $e^{iz}$ can't be $0$).

$$ X = \frac{2i \omega \pm \sqrt{-4\omega^2 + 4 }}{2} = i \omega \pm \sqrt{1 - \omega^2}$$

double roots in $0$ ? 
\begin{align*}
i \omega \pm \sqrt{1 - \omega^2} = 0  & \Rightarrow i \omega = \pm \sqrt{1 - \omega^2}\\
          & \Rightarrow - \omega^2 = 1 - \omega^2\\
          & \Rightarrow 0 = 1 \\
\end{align*}

So we always have a solution.

---

$$ \sin z = \omega \Rightarrow e^{iz} = i\omega \pm \sqrt{1-\omega^2}$$

\begin{align*}
\arcsin \omega = z  & \Rightarrow iz=\ln \left( -i\omega \pm \sqrt{1-\omega^2}\right) \\
     & \Rightarrow z= -i \ln \left( -i\omega \pm \sqrt{1-\omega^2}\right) \\
\end{align*}

Yet everywhere I look the $\pm$ is simply a $+$

---

**Question:** How to get rid of the $\pm$ ?

Comment: $\sin\theta=\sin(\pi-\theta)$.  $\arcsin x$ is often defined for real $x\in[-1,1]$ to be the angle between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, though other values exist with the same sine.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of that. As long as you can reach any value, this is just a choice as it is a multi-function!